# Change entities names in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

how to change names of elements in wordpress admin panel? For example change "Posts" on "Products", with all forms, existing anywhere. I know, that when I create my own taxonomy, I can set all the forms of it's name. May be I can make something like that for general names of entities like Posts and Pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the name in the `init` action hook, like so:

```
function change_post_object_label() {
    global $wp_post_types;

    $labels = &$wp_post_types['post']->labels;
    $labels->name = 'Products';
    $labels->singular_name = 'Product';
    $labels->add_new = 'Add Product';
    $labels->add_new_item = 'Add Product';
    $labels->edit_item = 'Edit Products';
    $labels->new_item = 'Product';
    $labels->view_item = 'View Product';
    $labels->search_items = 'Search Products';
    $labels->not_found = 'No Products found';
    $labels->not_found_in_trash = 'No Products found in Trash';
}
add_action( 'init', 'change_post_object_label' );
```

To change the Menu Label though you gotta use a separate hook: `admin_menu`

```
function edit_menu_items() {
    global $menu;
    global $submenu;

    $menu[5][0] = 'Products';
    $submenu['edit.php'][5][0] = 'Products';
    $submenu['edit.php'][10][0] = 'Add Product';
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'edit_menu_items');
```

Comment: thank you very much! I tried something with languages, but this is much better

Comment: Not a problem - future you should check out [The Official WordPress Exchange](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com)!